# If jQuery AJAX data is sent/received, is it possible to only receive SOME of the data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Let's assume this is being executed in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'ajaxcall.php',
    data : { 'data' : { ary : [1,2,3,3,4,5], txt : "ima let u finish" } },
    dataType : 'json',
    type : 'post',
    timeout : 10000
});
```

And ajaxcall.php contains:

```
$return_obj = array();
$return_obj['ary'] = array(9,8,7,6,5);
$return_obj['txt'] = "ok then";

echo json_encode($return_obj);
die();
```

I'm expecting the following situations to occur (due to packet loss, connection problems, etc):

- Ajaxcall.php executes, but the $_POST variable is empty.
- The promises of the $.ajax() call are executed, but the data returned to them is empty.

However, what I'm really worried about are situations like these:

- Ajaxcall.php executes and $_POST['data']['txt'] has expected values but $_POST['data']['ary'] is missing some values.
- The promises of the $.ajax() call are executed and data.ary has the expected values, but data.txt is only half a string (e.g., "ok t").

Are these situations possible?

Comment: This means the PHP code is doing something wrong - either incorrectly encoding the JSON wrong (but more likely the data is not expected) or returning a success header and terminating the stream prematurely (which should yield invalid JSON). The success callback of jQuery AJAX is *only* called on a success *after* all data is transfered.

Comment: Yup - open the browser debugger NETWORK panel and look at the response back. See if the response is malformed or incomplete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: no, that's not possible.  HTTP is based on TCP which guarantees delivery of data.  Both the server and client would be aware of an issue that would cause some data to be missed.  The TCP layer would retransmit the data as needed until it is complete.

Packet loss and out of order delivery are not uncommon the internet since there is no rule that says routers must forward all packets but TCP automatically corrects for those issues.

Answer (score 2):

None of these situations should happen.

Packet loss is managed at a lower level of the protocol stack.

Over the internet, [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) takes care of integrity of each packet and that all the packets arrive properly and in the right order.

On a higher level of the protocol stack, [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) has a response header called `Content-Length` that tells the browser the size of the returned content, it is used by the browser to make sure the response is complete.

Though, some HTTP requests can be answered with a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header that makes the `Content-Length` useless. These are persistent connections and are maily used when the length of the content is not known beforehand.

Do you have any example of cases where the data is not complete upon arrival?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I really understand your question, however if the response is somehow truncated (but returned - ie, the server still responds with a 200 status OK) it won't be valid JSON.

It's unclear from your question how `data.txt` could be 'only have a string' and yet remain valid.